# Сортировка строк двумерного list с применением StringComparer.Ordinal - C#

Tags: c#

Нужна сортировка строк двумерного list с применением StringComparer.Ordinal - C#

```
 List<List<string>> tbl = new List<List<string>>();
```

При равенстве элементов строк в 1-ом столбце, идет сортировка по 2-ому и т.д.

Пример:

На входе:

```
tbl ={
      { fedya, developer, html},
      { Ivan, manager, html},
      { Ivan, manager ,exe}
      { fedya, manager ,html}, }
```

На выходе:

```
tbl ={
       { Ivan, manager ,exe}
       { Ivan, manager ,html}, }
       { fedya, developer, html},
       { fedya, manager, html},
```

Comment: Что такое двумерный List?

Comment: List<List<string>> tbl = new List<List<string>>();

Comment: Вам же приводили пример кода с `OrderBy`. Просто примените далее `ThenBy` для второго, третьего и т. д. столбцов.

Comment: Напишите, как это будет с применением StringComparer.Ordinal, очень нужна сортировка сначала большие потом малые буквы

Answer (score 1):

Делаем `OrderBy` по 0-м элементам и, затем, `ThenBy` по остальным:

```
var list = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "fedya", "developer", "html"},
    new List<string> { "Ivan", "manager", "html"},
    new List<string> { "Ivan", "manager", "exe"},
    new List<string> { "fedya", "manager", "html"}
};

var result = list.OrderBy(x => x[0], StringComparer.Ordinal);
for (int i = 1; i < list[0].Count; ++i)
{
    // Очень важно скопировать в переменную с ограниченной областью видимости,
    //  для подробностей читайте про замыкания в C#
    int index = i;
    result = result.ThenBy(x => x[index], StringComparer.Ordinal);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x))));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Ivan, manager, exe
> Ivan, manager, html
> fedya, developer, html
> fedya, manager, html
> ```

Все вложенные списки должны иметь одинаковое количество элементов

Comment: А как добавить StringComparer.Ordinal ?

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, вторым параметром в OrderBy и ThenBy укажите

Comment: Сделайте пожалуйста и у вас вывод не такой, посмотрите в примере

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, ну естественно, если вы условия на лету меняете

Comment: Извините, так получилось, по заданию нужно

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, сделал

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, если мой ответ помог вам - примите его (галочка слева под кнопками для голосования)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так все отлично работает

```
table = table.OrderBy(x => x[0], StringComparer.Ordinal).ThenBy(x => x[1], 
StringComparer.Ordinal).ThenBy(x => x[2], StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

Comment: У меня тоже самое в ответе, просто для заранее неизвестного числа элементов. Если вам в итоге нужен List, то вы можете вызвать уже после цикла: `table = result.ToList()`